# como ocultar um item no menu

Tags: android, menu

Criei um `menu` com botões para salvar, voltar e adicionar, e gostaria que quando clicasse em adicionar ele fosse ocultado ou que seja desabilitado. Tentei utilizar `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_item);` no qual vi neste [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar) porém fica com riscado vermelho embaixo da linha e a mensagem `unreachable statement` é exibida quando passo o mouse por cima. alguma dica de como posso ocultar o item no menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta tu instanciar o menu:

```
Menu menu = navView.getMenu();
```

e setar o atributo `visible`

```
menu.findItem(R.id.my_item).setVisible(false);
```

Já o erro `unreachable statement` se dá a algum erro de lógica do seu código, que quer dizer que o a **declaração é inacessível**.

Talvez tu esteja dando um `return` na linha acima, por exemplo.

Comment: `navView` não é reconhecido

Comment: `navView` é o nome do meu atributo `NavigationView`. Basta alterar pro nome que vc está usando